# r- how to edit elements on x axis in image.plot

Tags: image, r

I have created a image plot for this data:

```
sample
         p         p.1         p.2         p.3         p.4
  p    1.0000000  0.24077171 -0.66666667 -0.49009803  0.61237244
  p.1  0.2407717  1.00000000  0.09028939 -0.83444087  0.14744196
  p.2 -0.6666667  0.09028939  1.00000000  0.21004201  0.10206207
  p.3 -0.4900980 -0.83444087  0.21004201  1.00000000 -0.08574929
  p.4  0.6123724  0.14744196  0.10206207 -0.08574929  1.00000000
```

Using this code:

```
  image.plot(sample,col=redblue(191), zlim=c(-1,1))
```

I get this image:
[image]

Instead of 0.0 0.2 0.4.. on x and y axes, I want p p.1 p.2...
How do I get that that?
Thank you for your time and consideration?

My heatmap looks like this:

[image]

its not symmetric. Can you please fix this?
I am using this code:

> shades=c(seq(-1,-0.5,length=64), seq(-0.5,0.5, length=64), seq(0.5,1,length=64))
>   heatmap.2(sample, dendrogram='none', symm=TRUE, Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, key=TRUE, cexCol=0.7, cexRow=1,scale="row", keysize=1, col=redblue(191), breaks=shades)

Comment: I sort of found a way to do it, but it's not very straightforward:       

    `image.plot(sample,col=rainbow(25), zlim=c(-1,1), axes=F);
    title(main="Graph");
    axis(1, at=seq(0,0.8,0.2), labels=rownames(sample));
    axis(2)`

For some reason, I wasn't able to directly make the x-axis labels. But after I used title(), I was allowed to create the x-axis labels. Someone might know how to do it more elegantly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a better-ish solution:

```
 par(mar=c(5,4.5,4,7))
 image(sample, col=rainbow(25), axes=F)  #redblue() doesn't work on my computer.
 axis(2)
 axis(1, at=seq(0,0.8,0.2), labels=rownames(sample))
 image.plot(sample, legend.only=T)
```

[image]

EDIT: Does the plot below look like what you are looking for?

```
 sample = cor(matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=20))
 image(cor(matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=20)), axes=F)
 mtext(text=c(paste("country",1:21)), side=2, line=0.3, at=seq(0,1,0.05), las=1, cex=0.8)
 mtext(text=c(paste("country",1:21)), side=1, line=0.3, at=seq(0,1,0.05), las=2, cex=0.8)
 image.plot(sample, legend.only=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this not the way I want it. 
I want it the way it shows in heatmap, is it possible?
I am unable to use heatmap because it produces unsymmetric plot

Comment: Could you show a sample heatmap so we know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question and included my heatmap image and the code which i am using. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Swapnil'Tux'Takle -EDIT: actually even your original code produced a symmetrical plot for me...Not sure what your problem really is..

Comment: can you please give me the code you used and upload the plot you got?
I might be able to figure something out from it.

Comment: I figured out the answer for heatmap, scale="row" was the problem. I removed it and its fixed.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Because I got an error message about scale="row", I removed it and forgot to mention it. Good that it's working for you now.