# How to plot matrix as-is in R using grayscale?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

How to plot the following matrix

```
> a<-matrix(c(-1,0,1,0),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    0
[2,]    1    0
```

as-is, i.e. in 2D, representing values in some palette, like grayscale?

Should get something like this:

[image]

while with

```
image(a,col=grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

I am getting this:

[image]

i.e. matrix is reoriented and rescaled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28046116/2994949

Answer (score 5):

Just transpose (`t`) your matrix

```
image(t(a),col=grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

If you want the labels to start counting from 1 instead of 0 do the following:
(Taken from here: [r- how to edit elements on x axis in image.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770550/r-how-to-edit-elements-on-x-axis-in-image-plot))

```
image(t(a),col=grey(seq(1, 0, length = 256)), axes = F)
axis(1, at=seq(1,nrow(a))-1, labels=seq(1,nrow(a)))
axis(2, at=seq(1,ncol(a))-1, labels=seq(1,ncol(a)))
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Column and row numbers are still lost. I wish to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with `ggplot2`. First reshape the data.

```
df <- reshape2::melt(a, varnames = c("y", "x"), value.name = "value")
```

Then plot that `data.frame` with `geom_raster`.

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", fill = "value")) + 
  geom_raster() +                        # same as image in base plot 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "column", breaks = c(1, 2)) + # name axis and choose breaks
  scale_y_reverse(name = "row", breaks = c(1, 2)) +       # reverse scale 
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "white", low = "black", guide = "none") +  # grayscale 
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)               # nicer theme
```