# Change X value to character in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, graph

I want to create an image plot for a matrix. And I used the following code,

```
image.plot(X)
```

My X is an n by n square matrix. And it is the

[image: graph]

I am wondering how can I change X value into a vector of characters since each row and column in the matrix refers to an object. For example, can I change the x value 0, 0.2, 0.4,...to "apple","pear","peach",etc? I tried the following which didn't work

```
image.plot(X,xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at=seq(1, 36, by=1), labels =j)
```

where j is the label I want.

Comment: It would be good to see your code ( what you have tried)

Comment: You mean you want to change the labels on the X axis of the plot?

Comment: Where does `image.plot()` come from? It is not a standard R function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770550/r-how-to-edit-elements-on-x-axis-in-image-plot